# What is the dirctional derivative of a norm?

Tags: implicit-differentiation

Usually norm is not differentiable function. But norm has directional derivative. 
What is the form dirctional derivative of a norm in a direction d?

Comment: Usually a given norm is not differentiable. What kind of norms are you thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

The norm$$f(x):=\|x\|_2=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2}$$
is differentiable at all points $x\ne0$. One has
$${\partial f\over\partial x_i}={2x_i\over 2\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2}}={x_i\over\|x\|_2}\qquad(1\leq i\leq n)\ ,$$
and therefore
$$\nabla f(x)={x\over\|x\|_2}\qquad(x\ne0)\ .$$
If $u$ is a given unit vector representing a certain direction then
$$D_uf(x):=\lim_{t\to0+}{f(x+t u)-f(x)\over t}=\nabla f(x)\cdot u={x\cdot u\over\|x\|_2}\ .$$
The directional derivatives as defined here exist even at $0$: One has
$$D_uf(0)=1$$
for all unit vectors $u$.

Comment: Your result is even true if the norm comes from an inner product $\langle.,.\rangle$, i.e., $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$.  Using the chain rule one finds that $$D_u\|x\|=\frac{\langle x,u\rangle}{\|x\|}.$$ And that allows a nice interpretation: it is the component of $u$ in direction $x$.